# Trying to read dictionary from text file

Tags: python

I have a text file having dictionaries like this -

```
account1 = {'email':'abc@test1', 'password':'abc321', 'securitycode':546987, 'name':'tester1', 'phone':236945744 }

account2 = {'email':'abc@test2.com', 'password':'abc123', 'securitycode':699999, 'name':'tester2', 'phone':666666666666 }
```

and I'm trying to read these dictionaries value with this code -

```
dicts_from_file = []
with open('account.txt','r') as inf:
  dict_from_file = eval(inf.read())


print (dicts_from_file)
```

but i get this traceback-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\Dell_test.py", line 15, in <module>
dict_from_file = eval(inf.read())
File "<string>", line 2
{'email':'abc@test2.com', 'password':'abc123', 'securitycode':699999, 
'name':'tester2', 'phone':666666666666 }
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anybody please help and guide whats wrong with this snippet?

Comment: why not just `import` it?

Comment: `eval` is rarely the ideal solution. Why is the file in that format to start with? Do you control that, and if so why not use a format more suited to serialisation? If it's valid Python code, why not call it a Python file and `import` it?

Comment: ast.literaleval() ?

Comment: can you please brief it with an example as im new to python. I will appreciate if you tell me the better way of doing thins..

I want to save some account info in a file and then use that info in the mid of code

Comment: @pissall `eval` only  works for simple expressions, btw, which is why this is failing.

Comment: @user3121891 then don't save it like this. Use one of the many serializaiton formats that exist, like JSON, yaml, or pickle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is hacky solution, using [imp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html) module:

```
import imp

accounts = imp.load_source('accounts', 'account.txt')

from accounts import *

print(accounts1)
# {'email':'abc@test1', 'password':'abc321', 'securitycode':546987, 'name':'tester1', 'phone':236945744 }
```

But, for future, i would suggest to you not to use this file format)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you should use a serialisation format, but assuming that is not under your control, there are hacky ways to do this.

Since you have valid python code, the simplest way is to just import it.  First rename your file from `account.txt` to `account.py` - or something similar, so long as it has the `.py` suffix.

If you just imported the module then you would not know the account names, assuming these are random and you need to retain them.  He is a way to get them into a list:

```
import account

dicts_from_file = [account.__dict__[i] for i in dir(account) if not i.startswith("__")]
print(dicts_from_file)
```

Possibly more useful, into a dictionary where the account names are the keys:

```
import account
import pprint

dict_names = [i for i in dir(account) if not i.startswith("__")]
dicts_from_file = {i:account.__dict__[i] for i in dict_names}
pprint.pprint(dicts_from_file)
```

Gives:

```
{'account1': {'email': 'abc@test1',
              'name': 'tester1',
              'password': 'abc321',
              'phone': 236945744,
              'securitycode': 546987},
 'account2': {'email': 'abc@test2.com',
              'name': 'tester2',
              'password': 'abc123',
              'phone': 666666666666,
              'securitycode': 699999}}
```